# Edit many inputs

Tags: input, edit

I have a problem about UI/UX
Design on mobile. There are 50 users, each user has 4 inputs (name,DOB,address and phone), so confirm step I show all of information of 50 users and put a "edit icon" in each user OR I just put 1 "edit icon" on top title? I prefer to put each "edit icon" in each user, so it is good ux?

Comment: Does "mobile" mean phone or tablet? I.e., will the entire data (50 contacts with four fields each) fit on one screen?

Comment: This question needs context. It sounds like this screen appears as part of a larger flow. What is the purpose of that flow? Who is the user and what are they trying to achieve? Are there always 50 users in this view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Less is more" when it comes to UI design, generally speaking. If the scrolling issue mentallurg mentioned isn't present because you're able to keep all fields above-the-fold, then just do the one Edit icon. Ensure that you're providing visual feedback to differentiate between the states (*e.g.,* form field borders can be in different colours depending on inactive vs. editable states).

Reverting individual entries might not be a necessary feature. It doesn't take a lot of user effort to re-key simple data manually, anyway. And these are simple fields: name,DOB,address and phone.

Answer (score -1):

The edit icon for each entry is better than a single edit icon for all.

User has better feeling of control. You give him the possibility to exactly know what entry will be edited. When there is a single edit icon, user clicks it and has to scroll to the needed entry. While scrolling, especially on mobile devices, user can unintentionally modify some entries. When you have a separate edit icon for each entry, this prevents such accidental modifications.

If user needs to modify several entries, has done a mistake and wants to revert it, then with a single icon you will have to revert all unsaved entries. But if there is a separate icon for each entry, user can save each entry separately and, if revert needed, only the current entry will be reverted.